# How to efficiently calculate PPMI on a sparse Matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix, information-theory

I would have thought that between the `R` packages `text2vec`, `tm`, `quanteda`, `svs`, `qlcMatrix` and `wordspace` there would be a function to calculate PPMI (*positive pointwise mutual information*) between terms and contexts (based on a matrix of term-term(context) co-occurrences) - but apparently not, so I went ahead and wrote one myself. Problem is, it's slow as molasses, probably because I am not very good with sparse matrices - and my tcms are on the order of 10k*20k, so they do need to be sparse.

From what I understand, `PMI = log( p(word, context) / (p(word)*p(context)) )`, hence I reason that:

```
           count(word_context_co-occurrence) / N
PMI = log( -------------------------------------  )
             count(word)/N * count(context)/N
```

Where `N` is the sum of all co-occurrences in the co-occurrence matrix. And PPMI is simply forcing all <0 values to be 0. (This is so far correct, right?)

With that in mind, here is an attempt at implementation:

```
library(Matrix)
set.seed(1)
pmat = matrix(sample(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,10),5*10,T), 5,10, byrow=T) # tiny example matrix; 
# rows are words, columns are contexts (words the row-words co-occur with, in a certain window in the text)
pmat = Matrix(pmat, sparse=T) # make it sparse

# calculate some things beforehand to make it faster
N = sum(pmat)
contextp = Matrix::colSums(pmat)/N # probabilities of contexts
wordp = Matrix::rowSums(pmat)/N    # probabilities of terms

# here goes nothing...
pmat2 = pmat
for(r in 1:nrow(pmat)){ # go term by term, calculate PPMI association with each of its contexts
  not0 = which(pmat[r, ] > 0)  # no need to consider 0 values (no co-occurrence)
  tmp = log( (pmat[r,not0] / N) / (wordp[r] * contextp[not0] )) # PMI
  tmp = ifelse(tmp < 0, 0, tmp)  # PPMI
  pmat2[r, not0] = tmp  # <-- THIS here is the slow part, replacing the old frequency values with the new PPMI weighted ones. 
}
# take a look:
round(pmat2,2)
```

What appears slow is not the calculcation itself, but putting the newly calculcated values into the sparse matrix (on this tiny example it's not bad, but if you make it thousands of rows by thousands of rows, even one iteration of this loop will take forever; constructing a new matrix with `rBind` seems a worse idea).

**What is a more efficient way to replace old values in such a sparse matrix with the new PPMI weighted values?** Either suggestions to change this code, or to use some existing function in some package I somehow have missed - are all fine.

Comment: Take a look to dev version of text2vec. Here is how I calculate PMI for extraction of phrases (collocations) - https://github.com/dselivanov/text2vec/blob/master/R/collocations.R#L57-L76.
Regarding your question - generally try to avoid element by element access in sparse matrices, it super inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out in the meanwhile, sort of, this works reasonably fast. I'll leave it here in case anybody else ends up facing the same problem. Also seems quite similar to approach linked in the comment to the question (thanks!).

```
# this is for a column-oriented sparse matrix; transpose if necessary
tcmrs = Matrix::rowSums(pmat)
tcmcs = Matrix::colSums(pmat)
N = sum(tcmrs)
colp = tcmcs/N
rowp = tcmrs/N
pp = pmat@p+1
ip = pmat@i+1
tmpx = rep(0,length(pmat@x)) # new values go here, just a numeric vector
# iterate through sparse matrix:
for(i in 1:(length(pmat@p)-1) ){ 
  ind = pp[i]:(pp[i+1]-1)
  not0 = ip[ind]
  icol = pmat@x[ind]
  tmp = log( (icol/N) / (rowp[not0] * colp[i] )) # PMI
  tmpx[ind] = tmp    
}
pmat@x = tmpx
# to convert to PPMI, replace <0 values with 0 and do a Matrix::drop0() on the object.
```